# update user model after a state transition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to fill my input values in an edit form, but my values im not being pass to the model.

I have a basic crud operation in my usersController

```
$scope.user = {
    address:{}
};

User.get().then(function (res) {
    if (res.data.fail) $state.go("logout");
    $scope.users = res.data;
});

$scope.createForm = function (form) {
    if(form.$valid){
        User.create($scope.user).then(function(res){
            if (res.data.fail) $state.go("logout");
            notify({
                message: "Success - Record created",
                classes: 'alert-info',
                templateUrl: $scope.inspiniaTemplate
            });
        })
    }
};

$scope.edit = function(id){
    User.details(id).then(function(res){
        if (res.data.fail) $state.go("logout");
        $state.go("main.edit_user");
        $scope.user = res.data;
    });
}
```

Now on my $scope.edit function i get the user value and I assigned this to the $scope.user, but the problem is that is not updating my state "main.edit_user" view.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name='firstName' ng-model="user.firstName" required>
```

Comment: You could always pass `res.data` as a parameter on your transition to `main.edit_user`.

Comment: Could you add a snippet or a JSFiddle for us to see your working code?